# Java Class type method

Tags: java

I have a home work in a java... I tried many ways, but, apparently, stackoverflow is a last :(

So, I have this class:

```
public final class Span {

    private final double length;

   public Span(){
        this(0);

   }

    public Span(double length) {
        this.length= length;

    }


    public double getLength(){

        return length;
    }
}

public final class Circle {

    private Span radius;

    //radius with double
    public Circle(double radius) {

    }

    // span
    public Circle(Span radius){
        this.radius= radius;

    }
    //calculate area.....
    public double area(double radius){

        return Math.PI * (radius * radius);

    }
```

But:

```
**private Span radius**; <---- This is necessary :(
```

I have to create  Span(type) radius (in Circle class), Span diameter and Span perimeter.

Comment: I'm afraid it's unclear what you're actually asking here. You say you need to declare a field - fine. So what are you asking?

Comment: what are you asking and what errors are you encountering?

Comment: If you need to implement Circle constructor with double parameter, simply create Span in this constructor like this: `this.radius = new Span(radius);`. I remember one of my teachers who were talking for many lectures about Java objects, inheritance etc. and never said how to create an object;)

Answer (score 1):

public final class Circle {

```
private Span radius;

//radius with double
public Circle(double radius) {
     this.radius = new Span(radius);
}

// span
public Circle(Span radius){
    this.radius= radius;

}
//calculate area.....
public double area(){

    return Math.PI * (radius.getLength() * radius.getLength());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see much value in the Span class over and above a raw double.  I can think of two features you could add that would make it more useful:

1. Negative lengths make no sense.  I'd add a check in the Span constructor to the throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if a length less than zero is passed it prior to assignment.
2. Encapsulating units along with the length (cm, m, inches, feet, etc.) would be an improvement.

Having those, you just need to be able to calculate using spans:

```
double perimeter = 2.0*Math.PI*Span.getLength();
```

You should not be setting radius once you construct the `Circle`.  Let it tell you what the area is using the original `Span`.